# Want a sha256 ssl cert,but i get sha1,why?

Tags: openssl, hashsum

I use this procedure

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -subj "/C=IT/ST=Lazio/L=Roma/O=Blu/CN=server.server.server" -keyout ssl.key -out ssl.req -passout file:"/root/pass" ;done
#sign certificate
openssl ca -passin file:"/root/pass" -out key.crt -infiles ssl.req ;done
#removepass
for i in *key;do openssl rsa -in $i -out $i -passin file:"/root/pass"  ;done
```

I have added -sha256,but generate a sha1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found
on openssl.cnf

```
default_days    = 1000          # how long to certify for
default_crl_days= 30            # how long before next CRL
default_md  = default        # use public key default MD
preserve    = no            # keep passed DN ordering
```

become

```
default_days    = 1000          # how long to certify for
default_crl_days= 30            # how long before next CRL
default_md  = sha256        # use public key sha256
preserve    = no            # keep passed DN ordering
```

and then work with

```
openssl req  -nodes -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -subj "/C=IT/ST=Lazio/L=Roma/O=Blu/CN=server.server.server" -keyout ssl.key -out ssl.req -passout file:"/root/pass"
```